# reg file by .bat in windows x64

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows64

I run reg file by .bat in windows x64 but my reg file add to `wow6432node`, and i want Add to :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Myproject`  in windows x64 .

My .bat file command :

```
%windir%\System32\regedt32.exe e5.reg
```

please help me

Thank you

Comment: By default your bat file added in wow6423node if your are using windows64 bit.i dont know why try this location.can you post you sample bat file code? or can you ask the question in more details?

Comment: How are you running the bat file?  Do you know there are 2 CMD.exe's?  The 64 bit one is typically in in C:\Windows\System32 and the 32 bit one is typically in C:\Windows\sysWOW64

Comment: I use C:\windows\System32\regedt32.exe e5.bat  file  and i know 2cmd exe .

Comment: I want add  my reg file by run bat file to this path (windows x64) : "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Myproject"

Comment: What do you mean by "windows x64"?  There is no such folder.

You are aware that the 64 bit CMD.exe is in C:\Windows\System32
And the 32 bit one is typically in C:\Windows\sysWOW64

The last 2 sentences are NOT a typo!  Do you have them swapped?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to solve it using a .reg file. But only in a BAT file, as fallow:

You must add /reg:64 at the end of the command line.
ex:

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background" /v "OEMBackground" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001 /f **/reg:64**

Source: [Wow6432Node and how to Deploy Registry settings to 64 bit systems via Sccm](http://brpoblog.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/deploy-registry-settings-to-64-bit-systems-via-sccm/)